# how to fill the ftable with own values from data.frame?

Tags: r

by default ftable puts count as a value... In this example I wanna have sum of "Alertness" column.

```
datafilename="http://personality-project.org/r/datasets/R.appendix2.data"
data.ex2=read.table(datafilename,header=T)   #read the data into a table
data.ex2                                      #show the data


ftable(data.ex2, row.vars = "Gender", col.vars = "Dosage" )
```

Comment: maybe this could help you `aggregate(Alertness ~ Dosage+Gender, data = data.ex2, FUN=sum)`

Comment: I want  to do this by `ftable` and wanna have a pivot table as an output. I want to have results the same as: `reshape2::dcast(x, Gender ~ Dosage, value.var = "Alertness", fun.aggregate = sum)` but wanna do this by ftable.